# Reading my own Youtube Channel Memberships

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a service-side PHP application that simply returns a list of my Youtube channel members. The documentation does not give a clear example on how to use this scope specifically and neither API key or OAuth credentials have worked so far. If I use API key I get an error saying "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal". So on getting this error I tried with OAuth client credentials, but the information I can find in the documentation suggests that I need the user to login via the browser to get the access token and then fetch the information, which will not work since this is a server-side standalone application.

I read that the Youtube API does not support service accounts but in a last ditch effort I tried with that as well, which gave me an error saying "Access forbidden. The request may not be properly authorized. Domain:youtube.common".

My goal is to create a simple page that only my Youtube members can access. I've looked into doing this from the other direction by fetching the users membership information as they login, but I cannot find any information whatsoever about that in the documentation so I have put that on ice for now (but if anyone have any information on that I would gladly go down that rabbit hole instead).

If anyone can shine some light on this I would greatly appreciate it.

**What I tried**

```php
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Test");

    $client->setScopes([
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator"
    ]);

    $client->setAuthConfig(base_path() . '/' . env('SECRETS_FILE'));

    $service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    $response = $service->members->listMembers('snippet');
    print_r($response);
```

**What I expected**

A list of member objects from my own Youtube channel

Comment: Try and find a video on YouTube that explains how to do it. Occasionally APIs assume you've got OAuth and  API Keys as a default prerequisite without explaining how to get them! Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jykW3AX8pEE

Comment: @JeremyThompson Hello! So the problem as mentioned is not that I don't know how to get credentials for the API. I have tried both API key and OAuth 2 credentials. I have defined the correct scope according to the documentation and logged in with my account that has the Youtube Membership enabled, but it still gives me "403 Forbidden". I can fetch other information about the channel, just not membership information for some reason.

Comment: `403 Forbidden` its hard to rule out the API Key or OAuth. If the other APIs work perhaps contact YouTube support.

Comment: @Kyukyu Can you share your channel id? Preferably if you could also share the channel id of the most recent of your members it could also help.